# find_package() - use older version if available, else use newer version

Tags: opencv, cmake

There is the standard CMake command:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
```

When both v2 and v3 are installed, v3 will be chosen.

Now, due to various issues, I want to use OpenCV v2 if available, but if not, fall forward to OpenCV v3. Unfortunately this is not a valid keyword:

```
find_package(OpenCV 2 AT_LEAST)
```

One solution might be:

```
find_package(OpenCV 2 REQUIRED)
if (NOT OpenCV_FOUND)
    find_package(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED)
endif()
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: In the solution the first `find_package()` call should be **without** *REQUIRED* keyword, otherwise absence of OpenCV2 will be treated by CMake as an error. As for "better way", I know no one. You current solution seems good for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some based on your solution

```
find_package(OpenCV 2 EXACT QUIET)
if (NOT OpenCV_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "OpenCV v2 not found. Trying to find OpenCV v3")
    find_package(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED)
endif()
```